# Adding target to UIControl

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrol

I'm trying to add target when my UIControl is being created but it is not triggering the action.

```
  var myObject : myObjected?
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    self.view.addSubview(self.myObjec())
}

func myObjec() -> myObjected {
    if myObject == nil {
        myObject = myObjected(frame:CGRectMake(20,100,320,200))
        myObject?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.myMethod(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TocuhUpInside)
    }

    return myObject!
}

func myMethod(sender : myObjected) {
    print(rand());
}
```

MyObjected is UIControl and even after control is added I don't see any action, myMethod is not being called.

EDIT: UIControl is added as subview on TestViewController and TestViewController is added as subview of PrimaryViewController.

I'm interacting with Control from PrimaryViewController.

Comment: where do you change the value of your object?

Comment: I have edited my question